# How to push string into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Something magical happen. I'm stuck. How to push string into array?

```
const createParamForm = (paramsForms, setParamsForms) => {
  console.log('TCL: createParamForm -> paramsForms', paramsForms)
  const id = `f${(+new Date()).toString(16)}`
  console.log('TCL: createParamForm -> id', id)
  const paramsFormsClone = cloneDeep(paramsForms)
  console.log('TCL: createParamForm -> paramsFormsClone', paramsFormsClone)
  console.log(paramsFormsClone.push('banan'))
  // setParamsForms(newParamsForms)
}
```

The logs:

[image]

Why i'm getting 1 instead of ['banan'] ??

Comment: Because the _return value_ of `push` is the new length of the array, not the array itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**: Instead of logging `paramsFormsClone`, you have been logged operation `paramsFormsClone.push('banan')` which returns the new length of the array(`1` here).

You have to change the code as:

```
const createParamForm = (paramsForms, setParamsForms) => {
  console.log('TCL: createParamForm -> paramsForms', paramsForms)
  const id = `f${(+new Date()).toString(16)}`
  console.log('TCL: createParamForm -> id', id)
  const paramsFormsClone = cloneDeep(paramsForms)
  console.log('TCL: createParamForm -> paramsFormsClone', paramsFormsClone)
  paramsFormsClone.push('banan')
  console.log(paramsFormsClone)
  // setParamsForms(newParamsForms)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array `push` returns the new length of the array, not the actual values in it. Your'e fine.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(paramsFormsClone.push('banan'));`
 statement return length of array.

Please check by using `console.log(paramsFormsClone);`

Answer (score 1):

As push() returns the new length of the array after changes hence in your case it returns 1.